# Error on SPfx connecting to sharepoint context

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I'm following the steps on the MS site *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint*

however, on the step that would enable the SPFx to get the current context of the page I'm blocked by an error, this is my code on the HelloWorld.tsx

```
return (
      <div className={ styles.helloWorld }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
          <div className={ styles.row }>
            <div className={ styles.column }>
              <span className={ styles.title }>Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
              <p className={ styles.subTitle }>Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.description)}</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{this.props.test2}</p>
              <p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.context.pageContext.web.title)}</p>
              <a href="https://aka.ms/spfx" className={ styles.button }>
                <span className={ styles.label }>Learn more</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

[image: this.context error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IWebPartNameProp.ts, add context like this:

```
import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";

export interface IJerryTestWpProps {
  description: string;
  context:WebPartContext;
}
```

In WebPartNameWebPart.ts,add context like this:

```
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IJerryTestWpProps> = React.createElement(
      JerryTestWp,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context:this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

In WebPartName.tsx, get web title from context like this:

```
<p className={ styles.description }>{escape(this.props.context.pageContext.web.title)}</p>
```

Reference:

[How to retrieve pageContext in SPFx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211810/how-to-retrieve-pagecontext-in-spfx)